# Source of Dzikov customs

Tags: minhag, books-generally, chasidut-hasidism

Does anyone know of a book of *minhagim* (practices) or a *sidur* (prayer book) of the *chasidim* of Dzikov (דזיקוב, sometimes דז׳יקוב)? (Or anything that would show their *minhagim*.)

---

Hebrewbooks.org doesn't seem to help: [I've](http://hebrewbooks.org/1503) [turned](http://hebrewbooks.org/35416) [up](http://hebrewbooks.org/35418) [some](http://hebrewbooks.org/35578) [volumes](http://hebrewbooks.org/35579) apparently from the *rebbeim* of Dzikov, but no book of *minhagim*. Likewise, I'm not seeing anything at Google Books.

Comment: I would really love to see a website that compiles minhagim of as many different communities as possible.  I guess it would be easy enough to start with [Chabad](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/) and [Breslev](http://www.nachalnovea.com/breslovcenter/articles/Breslov_Customs_Weekdays_1.pdf), but the communities with a less prominent internet presence are tougher.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22788 (Beta Israel), http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30617 (Skolyer)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44112 (Tschitschkov)

Comment: @yoel Nitei Gavriel?

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/135777 (Ruzhin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sefer Damasek Eliezer has in it Minhagei Dzikov.

http://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95.html?id=EICmHAAACAAJ

Comment: Are there two separate seforim named Damasek Eliezer? Googling the name turns up the sefer in connection with Vishnitz.

Comment: GershonGold, and now, thanks to the wonders of ILL, I have a copy (temporarily), and, yes, he does have it. Thanks again, and a checkmark.

Comment: @Chanoch There's a surprising number of them, actually. There's one by [R. Eliezer Tzvi Safrin](http://hebrewbooks.org/21911), one by [R. Eliezer Papo](http://www.virtualjudaica.com/Item/5655/Damesek_Eliezer), one by [R. Eliezer Nitzberg](http://www.amazon.com/Sefer-Damesek-Eliezer-Hebrew-Edition/dp/B0085RA0VE), and one by [R. Eliezer Zusman Sofer](http://www.amazon.com/Damesek-Eliezer-v-1-5-commentary-Pentateuch/dp/B0076JCQCI). And also there's R. Eliezer Hager, the Damasek Eliezer of Vizhnitz, who as far as I can tell did not author a sefer of that name.

Comment: That URL currently 404s. See http://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91.html?id=RxQRAQAAIAAJ for the book.