# Is there a Beta Israel Siddur?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, prayer-book, non-rabbinic-judaism, ethiopian-beta-israel

Ashkenazi siddurs are different from Sephardic siddurs, do [Beta Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Israel) Siddurs even exist?

Comment: Kinnard Hockenhull, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C - see picture in article

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10919 (Dzikov), http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30617 (Skolyer)

Comment: Can anyone comment on what 'officially' qualifies something as a siddur?

Answer (score 11):

There is a text called [שירת הקודש של ביתא ישראל - Holy Song of the House of Israel](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C)

It is centuries old.
It contains religious poetry including prayers.