# Siddur for Skolyer Chasidim

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, chasidut-hasidism, mesorah-tradition, communities

Is there a specific siddur for the minhag of the Skolyer Chasidim (Chasidim of Ukrainian town of Skole)?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10919 (Dzikov), http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22788 (Beta Israel)