# What are some of the minhagim of the Ruzhiner Chassidim?

Tags: minhag, chasidut-hasidism

I'd very much like to know some of the customs (minhagim) of the Ruzhin Chassidim. I am rather fascinated by the Ruzhiner Rebbes (Sadigura, Boyan, Shtefanesht, Chortkov, etc.) and the rather sophisticated and royal way in which they ran their particular courts. I have also heard that the Ruzhiner Rebbes claim descent from King David. Any sort of information such as the prayer nusach, talit/tefillin customs, Shabbath customs and more would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I know the Ruzhiner minhag for how to tie the tefillin shel yad onto the arm and hand is the same as Lubavitch

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruzhin_(Hasidic_dynasty)#:~:text=Ruzhin%20traditions,-To%20this%20day&text=Among%20the%20traditions%20practiced%20by,with%20calmness%20and%20self%2Ddiscipline.